# Design for user-defined condition-based actions on a (data) object

Tags: c#

I have a class with (nested) properties that define the configuration of a physical real-world object. For confidential purposes I can't show actual code, so assume it is a vehicle (car).

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public FuelTank FuelTank { get; set; }
    public IList<Tire> Tires { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a set of instructions that looks at the properties of the vehicle and makes any changes if conditions are met.

Say the tire tread depth is less than 3 mm, the car's tire is replaced and a cost item is added to a bill.

```
foreach (var tire in vehicle.Tires)
{
    if (tire.Tread < 3)
    {
         ReplaceTire(tire);
         AddToBill("New tire", "$99");
     }
}
```

I can place this kind of logic in a fancy class that would qualify as a repair package applied to a car:

```
public class VehicleRepairPackage
 {
    private Vehicle _vehicle;
    private Bill _bill;

    public VehicleRepairPackage(Vehicle vehicle, Bill bill)
    {
        _vehicle = vehicle;
        _bill = bill;
    }

    void CheckFuelTank()
    {
        // Check if the fuel tank is more than 50% full
        if (_vehicle.FuelTank.Fuel < 50)
        {
            _vehicle.FuelTank.Fuel = 100;
            bill.AddCost("Refuelled fuel tank", 35);
        }
    }

    void CheckTires()
    {
        foreach (var tire in vehicle.Tires)
        {
            if (tire.Tread < 3)
            {
                tire = new Tire();
                _bill.AddCost("New tire", "$99");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could define multiple repair packages (formalizing using interfaces) and have a 'Garage' object decide which package to apply on a car.

My question: I want the end-user of the webapp to define what is being done in the repair package. The user should be able to define what item to look at (e.g. fuel tank), define a condition (low on fuel) and set actions (increase fuel, add costs).

This requires a more generic approach. I've tried reflection, but that makes things extremely complicated. Are there any design patterns or solutions for this kind of problem, where the user defines conditional-based actions

Comment: I have a feeling that reflection would make stuff simpler instead of the other way around...